# SAP GUI incomplete error message

Tags: abap, sap-gui

When programming ABAP the SAP GUI gives hints about the error in the code.

Unfortunately the error messages are often displayed incompletely. Like in the screenshot below:

[image: Incomplete Error Message]

Is there a way to view the complete error message?

The suggestion to double click the message did not work. It just disappears then. Also placing the cursor on the error message and pressing F1 results in the message "No documenation available" like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Error messages look very different for me and usually include the line number. How exactly do you end up with this display?

Comment: It is a start routine of a transformation.

Comment: What version of SAP GUI are you using?

Comment: 730 Final Release. File Version 7300.3.11.1084

Comment: Interesting. In 740, my syntax errors from program check look like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3YFQp.png. 
It's worth noting that mine is buggy too (note the repetition), but at least it displays the whole message.

Comment: What statement gives following error?

Answer (score 0):

You can double click on an error message to show the full message. Another way is to set the cursor on the message and pressing F1.

If this is not the case, the message is not a generic SAP message.

Comment: It does not work on my machine. I double click on the error message and it disappears. Placing the cursor on the message and pressing F1 results in the message "No documentation available". What do I do wrong?

Comment: Then there is nothing more to show. Unfortunately, this is all you get.

This is probably because the message field has a fixed length. You can get an ABAP-er to debug the screen and retrieve the source.